# Fix Wordpress 301 redirect to post with slash

Tags: wordpress, redirect, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a blog post up at https://www.mysite.com/blog/mypost/ which loads fine.

However, https://www.mysite.com/blog/mypost redirects to a post on a different domain https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/mypost/

I have nginx setup as a reverse proxy to load mysite.com/blog from mysite.azurewebsites.net. I think that the redirect is being caused by Wordpress and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redirect is happening in wp-includes/canonical.php. It's looking at the HOST header. I setup nginx to reverse proxy to mysite.azurewebsites.net, but the correct solution was to [setup a custom domain on Azure](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns-web-site/).